# JMeter - WebDriver Sampler - Autofill name by Google Map

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a text field for filling the address. When entered few letters and the full wordings of location will be displayed. Normally it allow users to click on the full wordings for autofill the location. And this function is from Google Map. I am not sure how to get the autofill name from default Google Map in JMETER.

When I send keys ("57 Java") to text box, it will display "57 Java Road North Point" under the text box.

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.xpath("//input[@value='']")).sendKeys("57 java");
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These "suggestions" are loaded by [AJAX technology](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/five-ways-to-test-ajax-calls-with-selenium-webdriver) and being added to the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) as you're typing.

Not sure about your application, for "normal" Google Maps it can be located like:

```
//div[@class='suggest']
```

[image]

So these "suggestions" are normal HTML elements which can be "found" using any suitable [locator strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/getting_started_with_webdriver/locating_elements/#element-selection-strategies)